# How to correctly render an $el element on a BackBone View

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I had a view where I had a very basic list of registered users on the site, and some option like create, edit and delete all together on the same Backbone view and was working.

Since this is a learning exercise for me, now I wanted to decouple the main view form the details view or create view, so first thing I did was creating a new view for creating a user, which is a very basic form with 4 fields on it.

This is the code on the main view that calls the create user view

```
userCreate: function () {
  event.preventDefault();
  var createView = new viewAdminCV();
  createView.render();
}
```

and this is the render function on the viewAdminCV() view

```
el: $('#frameDetails'),

render: function() {
  this.$el.html(templateUserCreate);
}
```

There is no error if I execute this code, however nothing get rendered. If I replace the line

```
this.$el.html(templateUserCreate);
```

with

```
$('#frameDetails').html(templateUserCreate);
```

it works perfectly, but I want to understand why the $el is not working in this case, because I have it working in other views.

Appreciate you help.

In case is needed, the complete code is in this link
https://github.com/GabrielBarcia/UsersMod/blob/iss3/public/js/views/admin_CV.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, a you're finding the `#frameDetails` element "too early".  Its easy to forget that when you use what they call a "jQuery Element" instance, you're really running a function.  That means in your code, it's trying to find `#frameDetails` at the moment that you run "extend" on that Backbone.View.  What you want is to find the element at `new viewAdminCV()`  (I apologize if i sound confusing...).

BUT to fix this, there are three ways.  One is traditionally, you just need to play in the literal string without the jQuery wrapper, then Backbone will find it:

```
el: '#frameDetails',

render: function() {
  this.$el.html(templateUserCreate);
}
```

OR

you can wrap that with a handler

```
el: function(){
  return $('#frameDetails')
},

render: function() {
  this.$el.html(templateUserCreate);
}
```

OR an even slicker move, is you inject it from your "admin.js" file. Then you don't declare the "el" property in your `viewAdminCV` class:

```
userCreate: function () {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#btnUserCreate').prop( 'disabled', true );
  var createView = new viewAdminCV({ el: $('#frameDetails') });
  createView.render();
}
```

Comment: This is a great reply. I will look a better look later on the day and let you know because I am at work now.

Comment: As I said, very nice and complete answer. All the solutions worked well, I prefer either the first one or the third one. Actually, Ill implement the third one, cause I liked the flexibility. What I cannot understand is that I have the exact same setup that is not working on this case on the admin.js view and never had issues with it. Why the code works well for one view and not for another is a mistery to me at this point. Regardless, appreciate your time and good explanation on possible solutions.

Comment: No problem, Gabriel.  It's all about the order of things, so you can't grab something that's not rendered yet.  I see a lot of people do the `el: $('#frameDetails')`, which I found to be the most common mistake. It's all over StackOverflow! haha. =)

Answer (score -1):

You already have el as an object.

```
el: $('#frameDetails')
```

So you don't need to use $el while rendering.

Use:

```
el: $('#frameDetails'),
render: function() {
  this.el.html(templateUserCreate);
}
```

Comment: Just because you `el: $(...)` doesn't mean that `this.el` will be a jQuery wrapped DOM node.